# help formatting a google graph URL

Tags: url, image, graph

i have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Bin Frequency
6.0 0
5.9 0
5.8 0
5.7 0
5.6 0
5.5 0
5.4 0
5.3 0
5.2 0
5.1 0
5.0 0
4.9 0
4.8 0
4.7 0
4.6 0
4.5 0
4.4 0
4.3 0
4.2 0
4.1 0
4.0 0
3.9 0
3.8 0
3.7 0
3.6 0
3.5 0
3.4 2
3.3 4
3.2 2
3.1 2
3.0 4
2.9 5
2.8 5
2.7 1
2.6 0
2.5 1
2.4 1
2.3 2
2.2 3
2.1 1
2.0 0
1.9 1
1.8 0
1.7 1
1.6 1
1.5 1
1.4 0
1.3 0
1.2 0
1.1 0
1.0 0
0.9 0
0.8 0
0.7 0
0.6 0
0.5 0
0.4 0
0.3 0
0.2 0
0.1 0
0.0 0
```

and i want to make a google graph that would look like this:

[alt text http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/3761/45343878.png](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/3761/45343878.png)

thank you for your help!

here's the problem. it is giving me two different plots:
[image]

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .net, you can try 
http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/

Google also has their wizard to help you build a sample url
http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/

I believe you are specifying the wrong type of chart (line vs vertical bar)